# How to change error message in laravel nova

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-nova, laravel-localization

I use Laravel 8.83.16 and Nova 3.32 for admin area
Also I use Digitalcloud\MultilingualNova\Multilingual for lang in site

I create functional and fields for users
For example, field name

```php
Text::make('Name')
  ->sortable()
  ->rules('required', 'max:255'),
```

[image]

And when I try to create user I see error "validation.required".

How I can change error message?

I try to do it in "nova/resources/lang/en/validation.php" and nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am using NOVA in my project and the following code is working for me

create a file `resources/lang/en/validation.php` and put the following code.

```
 return [
    'required' => 'The :attribute field is required.',
  ]
```